# Find the value of this combinatorial sum. $\sum_{k=4}^{100}\binom{k-1}{3}$

Tags: combinatorics

How to compute this sum without laboring?

$$\sum_{k=4}^{100}\dbinom{k-1}{3}.$$

Is it possible to reduce this to a single combinatorial term?

Answer (score 1):

In the same spirit as Santosh Linkha $$\sum_{k=4}^{m}\dbinom{k-1}{3}  =\frac{1}{24}  m ~(m-1)~(m-2)~ (m-3) $$

Comment: Sorry, I edited your answer by mistake :-)

Comment: No problem at all ! You could even have improved my answer !! Did you notice where I am ? Cheers.

Comment: Yes, but MSE is in english :p

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you can prove by induction that

$$\sum_{k=p}^{n} {k \choose p}= {n+1 \choose p+1}$$

Proof on an example, and illustration [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583402/show-that-sum-n-2m-vphantom1n-choose-2-m1-choose-3/583413#583413).

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=4}^{100}\dbinom{k-1}{3}  = \sum_{k=4}^{100} \frac{(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)}{3!} = \sum_{k=4}^{100}\frac{k^3  - 6k^2 + 11k - 6}{6} \\ = \frac{1}{6} \sum_{k=4}^{100} \left(k^3 - 6k^2 + 11 k - 6\right) = \frac{1}{6} \sum_{k=1}^{100} \left(k^3 - 6k^2 + 11 k - 6\right)-  \frac 1 6 \sum_{k=1}^{3} \left(k^3 - 6k^2 + 11 k - 6\right)$$

then perhaps look into [sum of cubes and squares formula](http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/ira/infinity/answers/sm_sq_cb.html)??

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the factors of the sum, I was able to get this:
$$\dbinom{100}{4}$$

[This answer suggests a proof method.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/790042/28555)