# What is behind these series?

Tags: number-theory

I just found out (I am an amateur) that if I have the following series I get the following answers for the a nth number .  (each series is the sum of the previous one)

$$1 ,1 , 1, \dots,   1  $$

$$1,2,3,4,5, \dots, n/1! $$

$$1,3,6,10,15,21,28,\dots,  n(n+1)/2!$$

$$1,4,10,25,\dots, n(n+1)(n+2)/ 3! $$

$$1,5,15,40,\dots, n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)/4! $$

etc.

I am looking to find a logical explanation to this development

Comment: Have a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583402/show-that-sum-n-2m-vphantom1n-choose-2-m1-choose-3/583413#583413)

Comment: You could also look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/583469).

Answer (score 1):

You may have heard of Pascal's Triangle.  Each of these sequences fills a sloping line of the triangle.
It can be explaind by induction.  For example, 
$$\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{24}+\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}6=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}{24}$$
which shows that adding the fourth series gives the fifth seres.